# How can I put gold in my stash?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 2, I always kept a fair amount of gold in my stash as a way of saving for expensive items. It was gold that I wouldn't touch because it wasn't freely spent from my inventory.

In Diablo 3, can I put gold in my stash? If so, how? Do any of the stash upgrades include a way to save gold?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do not put gold in your stash. If you die, you do not drop gold, and gold is shared between all your characters of the same type (hardcore/softcore). You can trade Gold to your friends in trades.

Comment: that is actually false your gold is not shared between all your characters.